# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 64 Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode

While running my project I am getting this error. Can anybody tell what went wrong? I have run the script in its place but still getting this error.

[image: Build Error]

This is my Run script

```
./Rapporter/BIN/ConfigurationEncryptor $PROJECT_DIR/Rapporter/Resources/APIConfiguration.plist $PROJECT_DIR/Rapporter/Resources/APIConfiguration.enc

cp $PROJECT_DIR/Rapporter/Resources/APIConfiguration.enc ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}
```

The run script is fine. But the variable ${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH} resolves to a folder called "project name". Because of space in between the "project name" I was getting this error. So I have set folder name as just "project" and it worked!!.

Does anybody have an idea how I can set folder name as "project name" and still make this run script work?

Comment: Did you try putting the second argument of `cp` in quotes?

Comment: putting the second argument of ```cp``` in quotes worked for me. thanks @pckill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The run script is fine. But the variable ${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH} resolves to a folder called "project name". Because of space in between the "project name" I was getting this error. So as @pckill has added the comment, putting the second argument of `cp` in quotes worked.

`cp $PROJECT_DIR/Rapporter/Resources/APIConfiguration.enc ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/"${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"`